# C++ - Printing Map<struct,struct,constructor> types

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, struct, constructor

I currently have the following code:

```
struct LR0Item{
    LR0Item(const string& lhs_p, vector<string> rhs_p, int dpos_p)
     : lhs(lhs_p), rhs(rhs_p), dpos(dpos_p) {}
    string lhs;
    vector<string> rhs;
    int dpos;
};

struct Node{
    Node( LR0Item* lr) : item(lr) {}
    LR0Item* item;
    map<string, Node*> tr;
};

struct fizz{
    bool operator()(
                    const LR0Item &a,
                    const LR0Item &b) {
                        if(a.lhs != b.lhs)
                            return a.lhs<b.lhs;
                        if(a.dpos != b.dpos)
                            return a.dpos<b.dpos;
                        return a.rhs<b.rhs;
                    }
};

    vector<Node*> N;
    map<LR0Item,Node*,fizz> nmap;
```

I have some miscellaneous code to fill nmap with data.  I am wondering how I can print out the data in a nice format (transverse nmap).  Also I am not completely sure as to what 'fizz' is doing.

Comment: By printing in "nice" format, you meant how to transverse the `nmap` ?

Comment: You should check documentation of `map` to see what "fizz" is doing: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: @P0W Yes, I did mean transverse the nmap, edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint instead of writing the whole code :

```
typedef map<LR0Item,Node*,fizz> Mymap;

Mymap::iterator it = nmap.begin();

for(;it != nmap.end() ;++it) {

   //it->first is your key of type LR0Item
   //it->second is your value of type Node*
   LR0Item key = it->first ;
   Node* val_ptr = it->second;
   /*
   Now use key.lhs,  --> std::string
           key.rhs,  --> std::vector
           key.dpos  --> int

   And 
           val_ptr->item, --> LR0Item*
           val_ptr->tr    --> map of std::string as key and Node* as its value

   */
}
```

And for *"Also I am not completely sure as to what 'fizz' is doing."*

`fizz` is a functor used as custom comparator to insert elements into your map `nmap`

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Basically it first compares:

- string `lhs`, and if equal, then by
- int `dpos`,   and if equal, then by
- vector `rhs` [lexicographically](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)

Comment: I do have a question, when looping through val_ptr->tr   which is a map<string, Node*>  I get my program crashing unexpectedly after 1 or so iterations.  How would I access this 'tr' map?

Comment: any time I try to access val_ptr->tr I get a crash in my program, any ideas?

Comment: @Dohrann you probably should ask this on a new post